# SiteEdit Properties and Methods in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, siteedit

Can someone provide me the documentation of SiteEdit Properties and Methods used in Tridion 2011 SP1.
E.g: SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation(),This property is used at two different places with different parameters. 
I want a complete information regarding all such properties with their return types.

Answer (score 7):

All documentation can be found on http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion this will point you towards the API guides as well as the online documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method in the 2011 SP1 version of SiteEdit. That method was only available in the 1.3 version of SiteEdit, which is very outdated by now.

However, the good news is that you can still use the markup output by that Script Extension - even in the many versions that have been released since. You really should update your templates at some point, though - at least to use a newer version of the Script Extension (but ideally to use the Template Building Blocks instead).

So anyway, you need to check the Implementation Manual for SiteEdit 1.3 to get the method information.

For your convenience, I'll explain the 3 parameters here:

1. The Component Presentation to output. Type: ComponentPresentation. Mandatory.
2. The "swap label" to use. If set, you can only swap its position on the Page with a Component Presentation that uses the same label. Type: String. Optional, defaults to an empty string.
3. The HTML tag to use as a parent element. All CPs that are editable in SiteEdit must have a container element (so that it can show a border around it and generally know what is considered the content of that CP). Type: String. Optional, defaults to "span".